# TextBox Content Selection Issue in panel split container

Tags: c#, windows

C# Winforms

I am unable to select the content of a Text Box placed inside a fixed panel which is inside a split container.

Could anyone help me to find a solution for the above?

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: "Cannot able to select the contents in Text Box/s " what do you mean? you should be able to get it by addressing it right.

Comment: Share the code for the community to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to switch the order of childform.Show() and panel.Controls.Add(childform). If you add the child form before it is shown, you apparently cause this bug.

Please use MDI Forms to solve this issue.